# Flash/AS3 Use variable in multiple scenes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need a simple way to access a variable from different scenes. I already read a lot of answers but nothing worked.

There has to be a easy way to do this!

Comment: Variables are already accessible across all scenes. Can you please edit your question with an *example* of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this library:

https://github.com/inruntime/AS3-Global-Object

Usage:

```
import com.inruntime.utils.*

//This is need every time you'll use the Global Instance
public var $:Global = Global.getInstance();

$.x = 1;


//access it


trace($.x);


you can even pass functions

function myFunction(name:String){
    trace(name);
} 

$.myfunc = myFunction;


//use the function

$.myFunc("NoName");

//output
NoName
```

Answer (score -1):

All scenes are part of the same timeline, so any variable you place on the main timeline is *by default* accessible across all scenes:

```
// Scene 1 main timeline
var message:String = "Hello World";

// Scene 2 main timeline
trace(message); // "Hello World"
```

Likewise, the document class is shared across all scenes, so any vars defined on the document class can be accessed across all scenes.

Lastly, if you are looking for an easy way to access variables from *anywhere*, not just across scenes, you can use class static scope:

```
// Main.as
package {
    public class Main {
        public static var message:String;
    }
}

// from anywhere
Main.message = "Hello World";

// from anywhere else
trace(Main.message); // "Hello World"
```